# sending parameters from angular to spring

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm new in angular and spring. I want to let user if he forgot his password to send mail to reset it . My problem how to send from angular to spring these parameters:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("email") String userEmail, HttpServletRequest request
```

this is my code angular loginController.js:

```
    $scope.formData = {};
$scope.sentMail = function() {

    var data = new FormData();
    console.log('data :', data);

    data.append('email', $scope.account.mail);
    console.log('test 1 :', $scope.account.mail);
    console.log("sent mail");
    var _url = _contextPath + '/sentEmail'; 
    $http.post(_url, data, {
        withCredentials : false,
        transformRequest : angular.identity,
        headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }).error(function(response){
        console.log("Error : "+response.data);
    });

}
```

and this is my spring contoller:

```
@Autowired
EmailService emailService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sentEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processForgotPasswordForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("email") String userEmail, HttpServletRequest request)
{   
    User optional= usersService.findByEmail(userEmail);
    if(!(optional!= null))
    {           
        modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "We didn't find an account for that e-mail address.");
    }
    else{

        String appUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();
        SimpleMailMessage passwordResetEmail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        passwordResetEmail.setFrom("support@demo.com");
        passwordResetEmail.setTo(optional.getUserEmail());
        passwordResetEmail.setSubject("Password Reset Request");
        passwordResetEmail.setText("To reset your password, click the link below:\n" + appUrl);

        emailService.sendEmail(passwordResetEmail);
    }
    modelAndView.setViewName("forgotPassword");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this line correctly print out the user email? `console.log('test 1 :', $scope.account.mail);`

Comment: Also, why are you setting the `Content-Type` header to undefined?

Comment: Thanks for your response console.log('test 1 :', $scope.account.mail); it is just a  simple test

Comment: I know that, but does it print out the correct value for `$scope.account.mail`?

Comment: yes it print the right value

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your $scope variables are fine.
Your spring controller seems fine,
but you need to change your Content-type while sending request from angular side,

```
$http.post(_url, data, {
    withCredentials : false,
    transformRequest : angular.identity,
    headers : {
            'Content-Type' : undefined
    }
}).success(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).error(function(response){
    console.log("Error : "+response.data);
});
```

Instead of `Content-type: undefined`, use

```
headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

or

```
headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}
```

Try to use this variation

```
function sendMail($scope) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
}
```

also, Instead of this

```
var data = new FormData();
console.log('data :', data);

data.append('email', $scope.account.mail);
console.log('test 1 :', $scope.account.mail);
console.log("sent mail");
```

try

```
var data = {};
data.email =  $scope.account.mail;
```

Reference from : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Comment: thanks in advance, i will try that and i will tell you

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for me , i make all the change but still the same, the problem that just display the messages out of the  $http.

Comment: your spring controller is invoked when you are sending the request... ?

Comment: I added $http in function loginController($scope, loginService,UsersService, $state,$http) and error in spring :  org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'email' is not present

Comment: try removing headers from the request... i mean send a request without content type and headers..

Comment: and try this one more 
var data ={};
data.email = $scope.account.mail;

with/without headers.

problem might be in formData object.

Comment: i try that i got that mail sent with sucess but when i open my mail i dont find nothing

Comment: that you need to check in your spring controller.

Comment: yes you 'r right. I got this in my spring org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException:173 - Access is denied (user is anonymous);

Comment: for your mail application:  https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-java-mail-tutorial ,or,  http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/sending-e-mail-with-spring-mvc

Comment: @ Emen Emen .. If i solved your problem for which this question was raised, then you can accept my answer.. :)